# Server 17.10 pwmconfig finds no modules

Tags: server, 17.10, fancontrol

1. Installed lm-sensors
   1.5 installed fancontrol
2. Ran sensors-detect
3. Added modules (sudo modprobe coretemp jc42)
4. Ran pwmconfig
5. No pwm capable modules found

I have an intel S3420GPRX with x3470 processor. Two case fans and a CPU fan connected with 4 pins, I've tried changing the fan connections with no luck. Fans are all running at max speed and it's very loud.